# how can i fix this : AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.python.keras.api._v2.keras' has no attribute 'Dense'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.python.keras.api._v2.keras' has no attribute 'Dense'
 in model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu)) model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))model.add(tf.keras.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

Comment: post full code.

Answer (score 3):

In your last `model.add()` call, you try to use `tf.keras.Dense` instead of `tf.keras.layers.Dense`. Modify you code to the following:

```
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax) # <-- your typo was in this line
```